# Regex statement always returns false in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to check passwords to make sure they contain at least 1 uppercase, lowercase, and one number. I have looked into this but cannot find why every single time, it returns false. For example, I put in Thechedda123 , and it still returns false, and doesn't post to my database.

```
$password = $_GET["password"];
$regex = "^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z\d]{8,}$";
$query="INSERT INTO `users`(`username`, `password`, `school`, `grade`,`email`, `classes`, `firstname`, `lastname`) VALUES ('$username','$password','$school','$grade','$email','$school','$firstname','$firstname')";
if (preg_match($regex, $password)){
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if (!$result) {
        $message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
        $message  = 'Whole query: ' . $query;
        die($message);
    }
}else{
    $numb = 'true';
    $cap = 'true';
    if (preg_match($regex, $password)){
        $numb = 'false';
    }
    if (preg_match($regex, $password)){
        $cap = 'false';
    }
    echo $cap;
    echo $numb;
}
?>
```

Comment: Delimiters are lost. `$regex = '~^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z\d]{8,}$~';`

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: Please use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: Allow users to use the [passwords / phrases](https://xkcd.com/936/) they desire, [don't limit passwords](http://jayblanchard.net/security_fail_passwords.html)

Comment: One more thing. Passwords should not be allowed to exceed a limit. Your regex insist on more than 8 characters, but it should also impose a higher limit.

Comment: Allow users to use the [passwords / phrases](https://xkcd.com/936/) they desire. [Don't limit passwords](http://jayblanchard.net/security_fail_passwords.html) cc:/ @noob

Answer (score 0):

I edited and tested your regex. Replace your regex to this:

```
$regex = "/^((?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d))[a-zA-Z\d]{8,}$/";
```

And test:

```
$password_good = "Thecedda123"; // Ok

$password_bad_1 = "hechedda123"; // Upper case missed

$password_bad_2 = "TTTTTTTTTT123"; // Lower case missed

$password_bad_3 = "Thechedda"; // Digit missed

$password_bad_4 = "Th123"; // Less then 8 characters

$password_bad_5 = "1234567890"; // Letters missed

// Result:

echo preg_match($regex, $password_good); // true

echo preg_match($regex, $password_bad_1); // false

echo preg_match($regex, $password_bad_2); // false

echo preg_match($regex, $password_bad_3); // false

echo preg_match($regex, $password_bad_4); // false

echo preg_match($regex, $password_bad_5); // false
```

Comment: The regex - even if it works - is not correct. It must be anchored at the start. No need to use a quantifier on a group of lookaheads.

Comment: Ok, @WiktorStribiżew, I added anchors and removed quantifiers, it's working too ;)

Comment: Thank you very much! Sorry for the late response, I forgot to respond. Works very well!